# HTML5 History API and Bookmarking

Tags: javascript, html

What's the point of using the History API if the URLs that it creates aren't "real" URLs? Sure I can pushState as much as I want, but if I can't then include one of these URLs as a bookmark somewhere, what's the point? My real question is -- how do you set up a web server so that, regardless of the address entered, it loads only one web application (leaving the address intact so that I can then reference it using JavaScript to load relevant content)?

So, I could then use the History API to display the appropriate address and then have that bookmark actually work when the user returns later to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing fake about the URLs created from the history API. You simply need to handle them properly when visitors use them to load the entire page (via an external hyperlink or bookmark or what-not). You can either do this on the client side or the server side.

Handling the URLs server side will, of course, depend entirely on how you're developing your application and is a bit out of scope for this question.

On the client side, however, you'd have JavaScript parse the URL and then respond accordingly. I personally find the [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) plugin very good for this.

Include the plugin like so, including an absolute path to the root of your application with the `state` argument:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.address-1.3.min.js?state=/absolute/path/to/your/application"></script>`

Then you'd have `jQuery.address` parse the URL when the page loads and the DOM is ready:

```
// Handle the initial load and make the page look the way it's supposed to
$.address.init(function(e) {
    // Address and path details can be found in the event object.
    // Explore it a bit via console.log()
    console.log(e);
});
```

For a good, working example I recommend viewing the source of [this `jQuery.address` example](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/state/) as well as [the `jQuery.address` docs](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/docs/).

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough answer. So, based on the example link you provided, when I back up to http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/samples/, that sample says, "Simple PHP/mod_rewrite powered sample that demonstrates HTML5 state support," so would you assume they're using nwellcome's mod_rewrite to direct the incoming hyperlink and then updating the address state using jQuery.address once inside the application?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You'd ideally rewrite (not redirect!) all traffic below your application's URL to your application's exact URL (the same address you specify in the `state` argument). Apache uses mod_rewrite to achieve this, but any decent web server and web framework will offer a URL rewriting scheme of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

Take advantage of the [standard organization within URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme). Encode your state information in the query, which can be processed by client and server scripts, but always use the same base URL that points to your web application.

Comment: What I understand from your answer is that, instead of simply adding the content to the ULR as  "Base URL + '/somecontent' ", use something like "Base URL +  '?Variable1=SomeContentA&variable2=SomeContentB'  ".  Am I correct ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Apache, with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) you can direct however many URLs you want to the same resource on your server. That resource would then have to inspect the URL and dynamically create the page in the correct state, whether that is done server side or client side is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using a MVC framework, you can use `.htaccess` to handle this as [@nwellcome](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7125628/edit) mentioned :

```
# html5 pushstate (history) support:
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

source : [HTML5 History / pushState URLs, .htaccess and You](http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2012/code/htaccess-for-html5-history-pushstate-url-routing/)