# URL Rewriting for HTML5 History Server-Side Support

Tags: java, guice, html5-history

Assume that we have a single-page (`index.html`) web application that uses [HTML5 History API](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/browsers.html#the-history-interface) to provide access to the following URLs on the client side:

```
www.myapp.com/
www.myapp.com/screen1
www.myapp.com/screen2
```

**How would we provide support for `screen1` and `screen2` on the server side?**

Comment: You should sore history in fragment part (waht follows hash sign) ie. www.myapp.com/#screen1 www.myapp.com/#screen2 that woudl make it semantically the same page, but different part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Guice](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), we need to configure our server to invoke `RouteServlet` for our HTML5 URLs:

```java
serve("/screen1", "/screen2").with(RouteServlet.class);
```

**`RouteServlet.java`**

```java
@Singleton
public class RouteServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").include(req, resp);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the best solution if you **aren't using a MVC framework** is to use `.htaccess` :

```
# html5 pushstate (history) support:
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125353/html5-history-api-and-bookmarking/21220636#21220636)